# Realtime between Laravel and MySQL

Tags: mysql, laravel, real-time

I am developing a Laravel app connect to MySQL database, and I want to show the realtime records on Laravel when database has changed. I used to try Ajax, but I think that is not the best way. Can anyone give me a method?

Comment: Read https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use AJAX to achieve it by requesting Laravel every 5 seconds also. However, it will increase the load of the network and the heaviness of back-end. There are many useless requests made if there is no update on the server.

A better approach is to [broadcast](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting) the changed data to the client side when the server receives an update. Or, broadcast to client-side and ask the client(mostly Javascript) to make the AJAX request to the back-end.

Usually, you have to set up a Redis or you can use third-party service like [Pusher](https://pusher.com/).